# Efficient way to query PostgreSQL every 30 seconds?

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to fetch data(How many records waiting to be processed) from certain PostgreSQL Tables in AWS for reporting. The result of the qry is posted to a log and picked up by FluentD demons and pushed to elasticsearch/Kibana. The straight forward way to do this is write a small spring boot app that ping Db every 30 seconds or so. This, I feel, inefficient and costly. Is there a better way to this?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It's hard to suggest things without know more about how your system works, but this seems like it would be a good case for an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by a CloudWatch rule, though the minimum interval for those is every 1 minute

Comment: the use case here is very simple. do a raw count on a table every 30 second. post that data to Elastic search.

Comment: I understand the use case, but you have not provided any information on what your current architecture looks like. Adding a Lambda function can be easy or hard depending on how everything else is configured and managed.

Comment: Doesn't FluentD directly query RDMS, and also can insert into ES?

Comment: @Sïd your question seems to be very broad, can you please narrow it down to the issues you are having while querying to Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying DB periodically, use Change Data Capture (CDC) to produce a stream of change events. Using stream processing,  write the result to an Elasticsearch index. If you're not concerned about vendor locking, you can use AWS DMS, Kinesis and Lambda to do that. Otherwise, you can use a suitable Kafka connector to read the changes  and post the events on Kafka. Then using Kafka streams push the data to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Please note, using CDC pattern contains near real-time records, but, yes it reduces the load on the master database.

Comment: @sïd does this answer your query? If yes, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer